# Solaris get minus 5 min logs from trace file with specific timestamp

Tags: datetime, solaris

I have the following CHECK that works fine in Linux (and Unix) to grep for a specific error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" the logs of up to -5 min from current date and time:

```
CHECK=$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+[%-m/%-d/%y %H:%M:%S:%3N EEST]")" '$0 > d1' trace.log | grep "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError")
```

The logs have always the following timestamp format at each line (example):
[4/18/16 12:23:57:998 EEST]

I am trying to do the same at Solaris, but I get the following error response:

```
date: illegal option -- date=-5 min
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

I have been looking for a solution but I cannot find a convenient one yet.  I have found some info for date and time manipulation with perl and python, but they are not easy to use and transform to do the same as I need above (especially perl appears to quite tricky, I am not familiar). So, maybe perl and python are not the answer here.
Can you please help me to do the job ?
Thank you.

Comment: You're using GNU extensions to `date`.  Such extensions make your script non-portable.  The POSIX standard for `date` is here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html

Comment: Thank you for the link provided.  I have 3 questions: 1) Can I somehow have also milli-seconds?  It is not mentioned at the link provided, but it exists at my trace log at Solaris, so I think that it might be possible.   2) Can I have single digit month with single digit, just as 4 from 04 for April and also the same for day of month, e.g. for 5th April 2016 to have 4/5/2016?    3) (most importantly)  I still don't know how I can subtract 5 min from current date.

Comment: Right now and after your comments my date is:  date "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S".   How do I subtract 5 min from that date and also how do I get single digit month and day, when month and day are single digit, e.g. for 5 April 2016:  4/5/16

Comment: Anyone else that can help with my questions???